# Get Years Months and days from days

Tags: javascript

I seem to not be getting it. I have number of days, say 762 which will be 2 years(730 days each 365 days), 1 month(762-730), and 2 days(assuming every month has constant 30 days)

I need to do that on JS. this what I came up with:

```
days = 762;
ymd = {
    d: days % 30,
    m: Math.floor((days - (days % 30)) / 30),
    y: ((days - (days % 365)) / 365),
}
if (ymd.m > 12){
    ymd.y += Math.floor(ymd.m / 12);
    ymd.m =  ymd.m % 12;
}
console.log(ymd);
```

Well it's not working.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: it's not working?  What output are you actually getting?

Comment: Your logic, assuming there's not a great Date function that does this for you, should be altered.  First, calc the years by doing a floor of (days / 365) = 2.  Then, Subtract that result times 365 (762 - (365 * 2)) from the total days, leaving the number of days into the year.  Then do a floor on that result (32 / 30), to get the number of months, (different months have different lengths) = 1.  Then, subtract that (32 - (30 * 1)), and you will end up with a result that is the number of days.

Comment: well, i edited the question. the years is wrong.

Comment: I will LOVE to use Date built-in JS object! whats is name? and i will try what you just told me @cale_b.

Comment: @JohnnyJS your months are wrong. The years are fine. You need something like `Math.floor((days - (days % 30)) / 30) % 12`

Comment: Why aren't you using a Date object?

Comment: @Jonathan i will love to hear how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your assumptions on year/month lengths;

```
function dToYMD(i) {
    var y, m ,d;
    y = (i / 365) | 0;
    i = i - y * 365;
    m = (i /  30) | 0;
    i = i - m *  30;
    d =  i        | 0;
    return [y, m, d];
}
dToYMD(762); // [2 /* years */, 1 /* month */, 2 /* days */]
```

---

> I thought there was something built in. i meant using Date obj

This would not use your assumptions for lengths, but you could set a date based upon the unix epoch, and then minus `1970` from the year.

```
function dToYMD(i) {
    var d = new Date(i * 864e5);
    return [d.getUTCFullYear() - 1970, d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate() - 1];
}
dToYMD(762); // [2 /* years */, 1 /* month */, 1 /* days */]
```

Note this time, the number of days is different because *January* has `31` days.

Comment: Seems Awesome. I thought there was something built in. i meant using Date obj in some way, but math good too. i will check and then mark your answer. tnx.

Comment: is this a problem to return an object instead of array? it will really help me.

Comment: You can return whatever you like.

Comment: well i cracked it.. =) i changed the code to my specific needs: `return {y:y, m:m, d:d};`

Comment: @JohnnyJS See edit for how to do it using _Date_. n.b. `864e5` is _milliseconds_ in a _day_

Comment: well i dont know why but `dToYMD(10)` produce 11 days. besides you are Genius! i will learn a lot from those examples.

Comment: @JohnnyJS `.toUTCDate()` starts from `1` on the first day of the month, etc. so for your output you want to minus `1` from it (fixed now). I also explained why the output is now different for `762` days.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus (`%`) returns the remainder after a division. You should be using regular division then flooring the value.

Like so:

```
var numOfDays = 762;

var years = Math.floor(numOfDays / 365),
    months = Math.floor((numOfDays-(years*365)) / 30),
    days = ((numOfDays-(years*365))-months*30);
```

[Here is the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/eazimmerman/rMRTy/)